Proving that I've found all possible roots of $\sqrt{4-\sqrt{11}}^{x^2-9x+11}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{11}}^{x^2-9x+11}=2^{x^2-9x+12}$
Task is to solve equations (NOT algebraically).
In case it's not clear, that problem is a part of an assignment after a topic about applications of function properties (monotonicity, convexity, even or odd, periodic or not) in case of equations solving. So, not algebraically basically means, that you can't go straight forward due to extreme complexity of the such approach.
My basic intuition was to somehow find answers and after that prove that I've found all of them.
The equation itself is:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4 - \sqrt{11}}^{x^2 - 9x + 11} + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{11}}^{x^2 - 9x + 11} = 2^{x^2 - 9x + 12}
\end{align}
Steps to find answers was:
$$\begin{align}
n &= x^2 - 9x +11 \\
a &= \sqrt{4 - \sqrt{11}} \\
b &= \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{11}}
\end{align}$$
Substitute and then eq looks like that:
$$a^n + b^n = 2^{n+1}$$
It is relatively easy to find $n=0$:
$$a^0 + b^0 = 1+1 = 2$$
And was not so obvious for me, that root could be $n=2$:
$$\sqrt{4 - \sqrt{11}}^{2} + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{11}}^{2} = 2^{2+1}$$
$$4 - \sqrt{11} + 4 + \sqrt{11} = 4+4 = 8 = 2^3$$
The problem is to prove that I've found all the possible roots without usage of a side software. Of course, I've checked graphically (with GeoGebra), that no more roots are here, but how to prove it with a pencil and a paper only?

What do you mean by "not algebraically"?

Can you show why the solutions are all $\ge 0$? Hint: use the graph to guide you.

Can you clarify with various examples of "applications of function properties"? Also, what grade are you at?

@calvin-lin
Properties are monotonicity, even or odd, periodic or not and all that we can derive from that

@j-e-pin
I guess it's fair to say - solve it by abuse of a mentioned function properties, not just by basic algebra moves for eq solving

By $2t=x^2 - 9x + 11$
$$\sqrt{4 - \sqrt{11}}^{x^2 - 9x + 11} + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{11}}^{x^2 - 9x + 11} = 2^{x^2 - 9x + 12}$$
$$\iff f(t)=\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{11}}4\right)^t+ \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{11}}4\right)^t=2$$
and all boils down in showing that $f$ has only one critical point which is a minimum and therefore no more than $2$ solution exist which by inspection are $t=0$ and $t=1$.

To prove the claim we use the following properties of exponential function $a^x$ with $a>0$ which are continuous with domain over $\mathbb R$ and codomain over $\mathbb R^+$:

$a^x$ is strictly increasing for $a>1$
$a^x$ is strictly decreasing for $0<a<1$
$(a^x)'=a^x \log a$

Then we observe that for $f(t)=f_1(t)+f_2(t)$:

$f_1(t)=\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{11}}4\right)^t \implies f'_1(t)=f_1(t)\log\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{11}}4\right)$ is negative and strictly increasing with range $(-\infty,0)$
$f_2(t)=\left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{11}}4\right)^t \implies  f'_2(t)=f_2(t)\log\left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{11}}4\right)$ is positive and strictly increasing with range $(0,\infty)$

therefore $f'(t)=f'_1(t)+f'_2(t)$ is strictly increasing with range $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $f'(t)=0$ has exactly one solution $t_0$ which is a minimum for $f$ and since $f(1/2)<2$ the equation $f(t)=2$ has exactly $2$ real solutions.

As noticed in the comments by Lutz Lehmann, since for any $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$ we have $(a^x)''=a^x(\log a)^2>0$, then $f(t)$, which is the sum of strictly convex functions, ais strictly convex too and using convexity, by definition, we can't have more than two roots for $f(t)=2$.

You could also say that exponential functions are strictly convex, so is the sum of two. A strictly convex function has at most two roots (which is proven along the lines of your argument with the derivatives).

@LutzLehmann Yes of course, I was thinking that maybe it is a more advanced concept therefore I've used this way but maybe it is also a good alternative. Thanks

@lutz-lehmann mentioned the actual idea, that suits my request. So I leave my calculations here (basically the proof, that given function is strictly convex over the domain):
\begin{align}
     f(t)=(\frac{4 - \sqrt{11}}{4})^t + (\frac{4 + \sqrt{11}}{4})^t\\
        f(t)-\textit{continuous over the domain } \Rightarrow\\
        \textit{It's enough to show, that:} \\
        f(\frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}) < \frac{f(t_1) + f(t_2)}{2} \\
        \left(\frac{4 - \sqrt{11}}{4}\right)^{\frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}} + \left(\frac{4 + \sqrt{11}}{4}\right)^{\frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}} < \frac
        {\left(\frac{4 - \sqrt{11}}{4}\right)^{t_1} + \left(\frac{4 + \sqrt{11}}{4}\right)^{t_1} +
        \left(\frac{4 - \sqrt{11}}{4}\right)^{t_2} + \left(\frac{4 + \sqrt{11}}{4}\right)^{t_2}}{2}\\
        a^{\frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}} + b^{\frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}} < \frac{a^{t_1} + b^{t_1} + a^{t_2} +b^{t_2}}{2}\\
        \textit{due to inequality of arithmetic and geometric means:}\\
        \sqrt{a^{t_1}a^{t_2}} + \sqrt{b^{t_1}b^{t_2}} \leq \frac{a^{t_1} + a^{t_2}}{2} +\frac{b^{t_1} + b^{t_2}}{2} \\
        \textit{Because $a\neq b$:}\\
        \sqrt{a^{t_1}a^{t_2}} + \sqrt{b^{t_1}b^{t_2}} < \frac{a^{t_1} + a^{t_2}}{2} +\frac{b^{t_1} + b^{t_2}}{2} \blacksquare
\end{align}

Using convexity we can claim directly that we can't have more than $2$ roots. I can add that in my answer.

@user
Of course. But as I've mentioned (maybe it wasn't so clear), I've been forced to avoid higher lvl staff like derivatives. I just prove the same thing from a basic definition perspective.

ok, if we can use convexity, of course this is the more effective way
